# How do I modify my for loop to iterate x amount of time on character length?

Tags: javascript

How should I modify my for loop so that the `document.querySelector('.answer').style.marginTop = "-1rem";` iterates x amount of times? currently, it is not working, even though I change the value of I to a different number, nothing happens.

It will only happen once and that is because of the `if (display.length >= 21)`

```
function buttonPress(numbers) {

    let input = document.querySelector('.answer').innerText.split('\n').join('')+numbers
    let display = document.querySelector('.answer').innerHTML = input
    console.log(input)
  
    if (display.length >= 21) {

      for (let i = 0; i > display.length; i++) {
        document.querySelector('.answer').style.marginTop = "-1rem";
      }
    }
  }
```

Expected result output of screen behaviour with for loop:

```
|---------------|
|111111111111111|
|111111111111111|
|111111111111111|
|111111111111111|
|---------------|
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achive?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You could run the loop 1000 times nothing would change since you're always setting the same margin value ! Try to add the `i` to the value:
`document.querySelector('.answer').style.marginTop = -i+"rem";`

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is that when the number of input is 21 it shifts up 6 times, 7 times etc, whatever I set the iteration to

Comment: also @CesarePolonara, it does work,but pushes the text to high,its meant to just shift up by 1 rem and the next line fills,then shifts that line up so on so forth, updated the code so you can see the expected outcome